Start-up of tread results in kernel restart
I load data from an excel file into a dataframe. Then I want to check that dataframe for similar rows using fuzzywuzzy. To check progress I created a ProgressWindwow and moved the FuzzyWuzzy to another thread. Without this setup the program runs smoothly, but with the thread the kernel restarts every time the new thread is started.
I use Spyder on anaconda, but also from the command prompt, the kernel crashes.
I tried scaling down the excel file to only 5 rows, tried to isolate as much as possible, used logging and tried to find out with ChatGPT
am willing to share the code here, just don't know if that is appropriate?
class MainCleanUp():
def init(self, df):
super().init()
    self.initCleanup(df)
    

def initCleanup(self, df):
    
    self.df = df

    self.columns_to_compare = ['Location_ID','Address', 'City']
    self.column_weights = {
        'Location_ID': 0.5,
        'Address': 0.8,
        'City': 0.8,
    }
    
    self.fuzzy_comparison = FuzzyCompare(self.df, 
                                          self.columns_to_compare, 
                                          self.column_weights, 
                                          90)

     # Connect the finished signal to a custom handler
    self.fuzzy_comparison.worker.finished.connect(self.on_cleanup_finished)

def on_cleanup_finished(self, similar_pairs):
    print("Cleanup finished. Similar pairs found:", similar_pairs)
    # You can add any additional logic you want to execute when the cleanup is finished

class FuzzyCompareWorker(QObject):
progress = pyqtSignal(int)
finished = pyqtSignal(list)
def __init__(self, df, columns_to_compare, column_weights, threshold):
    super().__init__()
    self.df = df
    self.columns_to_compare = columns_to_compare
    self.column_weights = column_weights
    self.threshold = threshold

def run(self):
    similar_pairs = self.find_similar_pairs(self.df, self.columns_to_compare, column_weights=self.column_weights, threshold=self.threshold)
    self.finished.emit(similar_pairs)

def calculate_similarity(self, row1, row2, columns, column_weights=None):
    if column_weights is None:
        column_weights = {col: 1 for col in columns}

    score = 0
    total_weight = 0

    for col in columns:
        if pd.isna(row1[col]) or pd.isna(row2[col]):
            continue

        weight = column_weights.get(col, 1)
        similarity = fuzz.ratio(str(row1[col]), str(row2[col]))
        score += similarity * weight
        total_weight += weight

    if total_weight == 0:
        return 0

    return score / total_weight

def find_similar_pairs(self, df, columns, column_weights=None, threshold=80):
    num_rows = df.shape[0]
    similar_pairs = []
    comparisons_counter = 0
    total_comparisons = (num_rows * (num_rows - 1)) // 2

    steps = max(1, total_comparisons // 20)

    for i in range(num_rows):
        for j in range(i + 1, num_rows):
            score = self.calculate_similarity(df.iloc[i], df.iloc[j], columns, column_weights)
            if score > threshold:
                similar_pairs.append((i, j, score))

            comparisons_counter += 1

            if comparisons_counter % steps == 0:
                progress = int(comparisons_counter / total_comparisons * 100 + 1)
                self.progress.emit(progress)

    self.progress.emit(100)  # Ensure the progress bar completes
    return similar_pairs

class FuzzyCompare:
def __init__(self, df, columns_to_compare, column_weights, threshold):
    super().__init__()
    self.df = df
    self.columns_to_compare = columns_to_compare
    self.column_weights = column_weights
    self.threshold = threshold
    
    # Initialize the progress window
    self.progress_window = ProgressWindow()
    self.progress_window.show()

    # Set up the worker and the thread
    self.thread = QThread()
    self.worker = FuzzyCompareWorker(df, columns_to_compare, column_weights, threshold)
    self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)

    # Connect signals and slots
    self.worker.progress.connect(self.progress_window.update_progress)
    self.worker.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
    self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
    self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
    self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
    self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)

    # Start the thread
    self.thread.start()

def on_finished(self, similar_pairs):
    self.progress_window.close()
    print("Comparison finished. Similar pairs found:", similar_pairs)

class ProgressWindow(QWidget):
def init(self):
super().init()
self.initUI()
def initUI(self):
    self.setWindowTitle('Progress')
    self.setGeometry(150, 150, 300, 100)

    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    self.progress_bar = QProgressBar(self)
    self.progress_bar.setMinimum(0)
    self.progress_bar.setMaximum(100)
    layout.addWidget(self.progress_bar)
    
    self.setLayout(layout)

def update_progress(self, value):
    self.progressBar.setValue(value)

def closeEvent(self, event):
    # Override to handle the close event if necessary
    event.accept()

